# how get parameter with POST method from rest client to php

Tags: php, rest

i need to save in a folder on server pdfs and in a db the relative url.
but with the code that i show you below i get the error in php:"`please choose a file`"...i don't know why.

I show you my code:

REST CLIENT SIDE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpSel.jpg)

SERVER SIDE:

```
<?php
//importing dbDetails file
require_once 'dbDetails.php';

//this is our upload folder
$upload_path = 'uploads/';

//Getting the server ip
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());



//creating the upload url
//$upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/AndroidImageUpload/'.$upload_path;
$upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/azz/'.$upload_path;


//response array
$response = array();


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //checking the required parameters from the request
    if( isset($_POST['nome_pdf'])  && isset($_FILES['pdf']['nome_pdf']) && isset($_POST['id'])){

        //connecting to the database
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect...');

        //getting name from the request
        $nome = $_POST['nome_pdf'];



        //getting file info from the request
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['pdf']['nome_pdf']);




        //getting the file extension
        $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

        $id = $_POST['id'];


        //file url to store in the database
        $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;


        //file path to upload in the server
        $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension;

        //trying to save the file in the directory
        try{
            //saving the file
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],$file_path);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `my_db`.`pdfss` (`id_pdf`, `nome_pdf`, `url_pdf`,`id_user`) VALUES (NULL, '$nome','$file_url', '$id');";

            //adding the path and name to database
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                //filling response array with values
                $response['error'] = false;
               //  $response['url'] = $file_url;
//                 $response['name'] = $name;
                 $response['nome_pdf'] = $nome;
                 $response['url_pdf'] = $file_url;
            }
            //if some error occurred
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
        } 
        //closing the connection
        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']='Please choose a file';
    }

    //displaying the response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I hope that you can help me!

Comment: this `['nome_pdf']` is not valid.use `tmp_name`

Comment: Also your script is at a really high risk of SQL injection. Visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about prepared statements and use them, otherwise your DB can be hacked in a few seconds. Also you should use auto increment on your ID field.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from here

```
 isset($_FILES['pdf']['nome_pdf'])
```

NOTE: You do not use `$_POST` when dealing with file uploads in PHP. Use `$_FILES`. I think you are confused with the name of the file and also the `array_keys` that are associated with the `$_FILES` `array`

nome_pdf is not in the `$_FILES` array. If you try a dump of `var_dump($_FILES['pdf']);`, you will see that `nome_pdf` is not in the array.

Replace the line with:

```
if( isset($_FILES['pdf'])  && $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'] != '' && isset($_POST['id'])){
#add your code
else{
$response['error']=true;
  $response['message']= 'PDF FILE: '. $_FILES['pdf'].' ID of post: '.$_POST['id'];
   exit;
}
echo(json_encode($reponse));
```

The above change will make sure the `tmp_name` is not empty. 
Also before moving the file, i suggest using mime type to check for the extensions

Comment: just made a change again. try now

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
if( isset($_POST['nome_pdf'])  && isset($_FILES['pdf']['nome_pdf']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
```

Should be

```
if( isset($_POST['nome_pdf'])  && isset($_FILES['nome_pdf']['tmp_name']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
```

Or

```
if( isset($_POST['nome_pdf'])  && isset($_FILES['nome_pdf']['name']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
```

Comment: In the form are you using  enctype="multipart/form-data" 
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: try var_dump($_FILES['pdf']); or var_dump($_FILES['nome_pdf']); and see what variables are available